# Rational functions in Python

Tags: python, numpy, polynomials

I would like use Python to verify the following identities:

- $ \frac{1}{1-z}  = 1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + \dots $
- $ \frac{1}{1-z - z^2}  = 1 + z + 2z^2 + 3z^3 + \dots $
- $ q \prod_{n \geq 1} (1 - q^n)^{24} = q - 24 q^2 + 252 q^3 + \dots$

The last one could be evaluated by checking the `poly1d` class in numpy.

Python doesn't seem to have a Laurent series or rational functions capability for the first two examples.

Perhaps there are numerical methods for generating these coefficients very quickly.  I am not sure what a good data type for storing series with potentially negative exponents.

Another possibility might be to manipulate [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to verify the above equalities for *any* values of $z$ and $q$ or for *specific* values?

Comment: try the web site Wolfram alpha. use the series command. very easy.

Answer (score 9):

I think you are looking for capabilities not available in Python itself nor Numpy, but that are available in [SymPy](http://sympy.org). Sympy is a computer algebra package developed in Python. You can try it "live" [in its on-line shell](http://live.sympy.org). Documentation on series development can be found [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/series/index.html).